# Why Steam OpenID redirect me to error dgango view?

Tags: python, django, openid, steam, python-social-auth

I'm using django, python social auth and Steam.
For logging I sent get request to Steam ({% url social: begin steam %}),
and I got Steam logging page. I passed my login and password and pressed log in. After that I was redirect to error url (not on success url). It's mean I was logged only in Steam, but not in my web site.
So why does it happened?

Answer (score 0):

I added this variables in settings.py, when I deleted them my site start working as I expect.

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_DISCONNECT_PIPELINE = (
# Verifies that the social association can be disconnected from the current
# user (ensure that the user login mechanism is not compromised by this
# disconnection).
'social.pipeline.disconnect.allowed_to_disconnect',

# Collects the social associations to disconnect.
'social.pipeline.disconnect.get_entries',

# Revoke any access_token when possible.
'social.pipeline.disconnect.revoke_tokens',

# Removes the social associations.
'social.pipeline.disconnect.disconnect',

)
```